# Is it possible to retrieve data from .IBD files using ibd2sdi - Mysql 8

Tags: extract

I am using Mysql 8 and system got crashed .

Is it possible to retrieve data from .IBD files using ibd2sdi - Mysql 8.
I tried running ibd2sdi I can get the structure but How to extract the data ?

But learned that data is stored in .ibd files. Is it possible to extract the data. If so how can I retrieve the data

ibd2sdi filename.ibd filename.txt